# How to decode hex code in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, hex, decoding

Need to decode hex code in array when accessed by index.User should enter array index and get decoded hex in array as output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  class Find {

  static String[] data={ " \\x6C\\x65\\x6E\\x67\\x74\\x68",
                       "\\x73\\x68\\x69\\x66\\x74"

                           //....etc upto 850 index

                        };

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a number");

  int s = in.nextInt();

  String decodeinput=data[s];

                          // need to add some code here 
                          //to decode hex and store to a string decodeoutput to print it

  String decodeoutput=......

  System.out.println();
                                          }
              }
```

How about using...

```
              String hexString ="some hex string";    

              byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hexString .toCharArray());

              System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Some remarks: in Java, classes always start with an upper case letter and variables ar writtein in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) and `[]` should be written behind the type, not behind the name (so `String args[]` becomes `String[] args`). If you want people to answer your question, you might want to format your code porperly (with regards to the remarks above as well as code indentation).

Comment: ok..thax for the remark @Turing85

Comment: [Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the following code after getting the value of s from user. Imp: Please use camelCase convention for naming variables as pointed out above. I have just gone ahead and used the same names as you have for your convinience for now.

```
    if (s>= 0 && s < data.length) {
            String decodeinput = data[s].trim();

            StringBuilder decodeoutput = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 2; i < decodeinput.length() - 1; i += 4) {
                // Extract the hex values in pairs
                String temp = decodeinput.substring(i, (i + 2));
                // convert hex to decimal equivalent and then convert it to character
                decodeoutput.append((char) Integer.parseInt(temp, 16));
            }
            System.out.println("ASCII equivalent : " + decodeoutput.toString());
     }
```

OR, just complete what you were doing:

```
/*      import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
        import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
        import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex; //present in commons-codec-1.7.jar
*/
        if (s>= 0 && s < data.length)  {
            String hexString =data[s].trim();
            hexString = hexString.replace("\\x", "");
            byte[] bytes;
            try {
                bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());
                System.out.println("ASCII equivalent : " + new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (DecoderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The solution was informative.I used the first code and it worked for me.When i used 
`Hex.decodeHex(hexString .toCharArray());`
I got an error.Is there any need to import special package for Hex.decodehex @user403348255

Comment: Yes as indicated in commented part of code above: import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex; //present in commons-codec-1.7.jar             . You will have to download the jar and add it to your classpath.